# How to install Git Bash with Azure Worker Role?

Tags: git, bash, azure, installation, azure-worker-roles

In my Azure Cloud Service application I want to setup Git Bash.
To do this I followed [this documentation](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-%E2%80%93-what-are-the-options/).
I think the best way is to do that, to create a startup script, called it  startup.cmd` whose content is the following:

```
 powershell -c 
 "(new-objectsystem.net.webclient).downloadfile
 ("https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140611  /Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe", "Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe")
 Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe /passive
```

I set a startup task at `ServiceDefinition.csdef` and after I start debugging. 
The Visual Studio says:

> Role instances are taking longer than expected to start. Do you want to continue waiting?

I know to run this `setup.exe` the installer needs a lot user interaction, so it won't install either.

But how can I install Git Bash to the local disk of the Azure Cloud Service?

Comment: When you say "this setup.exe this installer needs a lot of user interaction", are you referring to the Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe?  What "setup.exe" are you referring to?  Also, I find it helpful to log the output of your commands.  It may also be helpful to set the startup task to 'background' mode so you can RDP into the server to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, I referring the Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe.  I mean that to install Git user has to click the Next button several times or select some options.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to do that without user interaction (a quite install).  If the installer is waiting for user interaction, and the task is a "simple" task, that task might never complete.